# AWS AMB Private network connection with Hardhat

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, hardhat, amazon-managed-blockchain

I have successfully established a Private Blockchain utilizing the AWS Managed Blockchain (AMB) service. Concurrently, I am managing an application through the Amplify service. In an effort to integrate the two systems, I have appended a node application to my existing React application on Amplify. This node application utilizes Hardhat to establish a connection with my Private Blockchain on AMB.

My current challenge lies in properly configuring the hardhat.config.ts file within the node application. I am unable to discern the appropriate URL to integrate into this configuration file. Given your proficiency in this domain, I kindly request your assistance in composing the configuration settings accurately.

- hardhat.config.ts configuration with aws amb private network